# Creating External List

Tags: external-content-type, external-list

I have been asked to research **External Lists**.
After exploration I came to know that in order to use data which isn't there on SharePoint we make use of External List.

Now can anyone tell me a real world **example** of where exactly we can make use of this External List and what are the other things **possible** while using External List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets consider an example that you have your data in SQL Server and you want to display in SharePoint site.

So in this case you can create External List (**`BCS`**)

If you want to learn how to create an External List then please go through [How to: Create External Lists in SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558778(v=office.14).aspx)

More references

- [Differences between native and external lists](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-native-and-external-lists-6601eda9-b722-4bf8-a2bf-ce25cf3d2fd0)
- [Create External List in SharePoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/create-external-list-in-sharepoint-2013/)

For knowing limitations using External List please refer [25 Limitations of External Lists in SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/03/limitations-of-external-lists-in-sharepoint-2010.html)